# ROS urdf for Moveit!

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, moveit, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am currently working on a project, i am using servo motors to build a robotic arm.
The arm is aligned vertically, the gripper points to the sky.
In the joint description i wrote (urdf):

```
<limit effort="1.0" lower="0" upper="1.88" velocity="0.5"/>
```

meaning the joint state publisher will publish a state in the interval 0-1.88 radian (=120 grades).
so my servos are moving 120 grades, 60 grades in each direction and are set to the center.
When i start ROS Moveit! it publishes 0, for the initial positions, while i need 60 grades.
Any ideas how can i fix this?
How can i configure the urdf to start publishing positions in the center of the domain, causing a right move of my robot arm?

Thanks,
TkrA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209889/ros-urdf-for-moveit!/) by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-05-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-26**:
Just a comment, but your issue isn't only with MoveIt obviously: anything that uses urdf (and the joint definitions in yours) is going to assume that `0` rad is your robot's zero-position.

**Comment by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on 2015-05-27**:
Yes, i thought there are some settings i can make in the urdf file, to define the correct zero-position. Until now i could't find anything.
Thanks!

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-05-27**:
You might be able to hack this together with a mimic joint that has an offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found the answer:
reading the code [joint_state_publisher](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/indigo-devel/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)

```
minval = float(limit.getAttribute('lower'))
maxval = float(limit.getAttribute('upper'))
```

..

```
if minval > 0 or maxval < 0:
zeroval = (maxval + minval)/2
```

meaning if i wrote in the urdf

```
<limit effort="1.0" lower="0.001" upper="1.88" velocity="0.5"/>
```

the robot's zero postition=zeroval (middle)

---

Originally posted by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) with karma: 45 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0